# Local binary pattern python code for a 6 class dataset

Tags: python

I need the code for local binary pattern for a dataset with six classes in python. The below code is working only for single image. How can this code loop for a entire dataset with six classes?

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import PIL
from skimage.feature import local_binary_pattern
import pickle

feat_lbp = local_binary_pattern(img_arr,8,1,'uniform')
feat_lbp=np.uint8((feat_lbp/feat_lbp.max())*255)
lbp_img= PIL.Image.fromarray(feat_lbp)
plt.imshow(lbp_img,cmap='gray')
```